# Vuestic va-data-table custom cell template with complex value

Tags: vuejs3, vuestic

According to [slots docs](https://vuestic.dev/en/ui-elements/data-table#slots) I can customize the cell of a column like below

```html
 <template>
  <va-data-table :items="items" :columns="columns">
  <template #cell(street)="{ value }"><va-chip size="small">{{ value }}</va-chip></template>
  </va-data-table>
</template>
```

In my case, `value` is an Object, and it seems to be converted to string before being available to the template (which results in the cells containing the string [object Object]).

What I would like to do is something like:

```html
 ...
  <template #cell(street)="{ value }"><va-chip size="small">{{ value.number }}, {{ value.streetName }}</va-chip></template>
...
```

Is it possible for `value` to be available as an object in the template? Or is `value` a string by design?

Right now, I am solving it by encoding everything I need in the same string and splitting it back in the elements I am interested in directly in the template:
In the example below, `value="132, Oscar Street`

```html
 ...
  <template #cell(street)="{ value }"><va-chip size="small">{{ splitValue(value)[0] }}, {{ splitValue(value)[1] }}</va-chip></template>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found to achieve this is to use the rowData property like so:

```
<template #cell(street)="{ rowData }"><va-chip size="small">{{ rowData.street.number }}, {{ rowData.street.streetName }}</va-chip></template>
```

Documentation in the Vuestic docs is generally a bit light for what you're trying to achieve here, but as at March 2023 it is currently mentioned in https://vuestic.dev/en/ui-elements/data-table#expandable-rows
... works not only for expandable rows but for any template.

Comment: I ended up going with the themed AG Grid solution they offer. Its more feature rich, I could more easily customize it and I could define "frozen/sticky" columns (fixed ones that did not roll with the others).